# Integrate $\int_0^1 \min(1, \sqrt{x^{-2}-1})dx$.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I'm searching for efficient methods to integrate the left side of the following equality:
$$
\int_0^1 \min(1, \sqrt{x^{-2}-1})dx = \log(1+\sqrt{2}).
$$
This is on page 105 of *Probability and Random Processes* (Grimmett, 2001). My attempt so far has been to split the integral at $x=1/\sqrt{2}$ but the resulting integral
$$
\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 \sqrt{x^{-2}-1}dx
$$
seems a little messy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use $x=\sin\theta, \; dx=\cos\theta d\theta$ to get

$\displaystyle\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1
\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}dx=\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\;dx=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin\theta}d\theta=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}(\csc\theta-\sin\theta)d\theta$

$\displaystyle=\big[-\ln\big|\csc\theta+\cot\theta\big|+\cos\theta\big]_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}=\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.