# Solve $\int_{0}^{1} \min \left\{1, \sqrt{x^{-2}-1}\right\} d x=\log (1+\sqrt{2})$ (cf. Probability and Random Processes by Grimmett)

Tags: probability, integration, conditional-probability

I'm currently reading the book Probability and Random Processes by Grimmett and there is an example that I want to understand, it is the example $3)$ in the section 4.6 Conditional distributions and conditional expectation.
To be more precise, it is about the integral below

\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}\left(X^{2}+Y^{2} \leq 1\right) &=\iint_{A} f_{X, Y}(x, y) d x d y \\
&=\int_{x=0}^{1} f_{X}(x) \int_{y \in A(x)} f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) d y d x \\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \min \left\{1, \sqrt{x^{-2}-1}\right\} d x=\log (1+\sqrt{2})
\end{aligned}

where $$
f_{X, Y}(x, y)=\frac{1}{x}, \quad 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1 .
$$

$$
f_{X}(x)=1 \quad \text { if } \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1, \quad f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x)=\frac{1}{x} \quad \text { if } \quad 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1,
$$

I don't understand how he solved the integral to find $\log(1 + \sqrt{2})$. Has someone an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help you : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332097/integrate-int-01-min1-sqrtx-2-1dx?rq=1 ?